# Can I farm more than one of each key before crafting my Infernal Machine(s)?

Tags: diablo-iii

I plan on farming Act 1 for a while, as I've done so much Act 3 farming I'm quite bored with it.

I've added Fields of Misery to my farming path once I get 5 NV stacks, so I can get my first key.

However, once it drops, will I be able to continue farming more Act 1 keys?  I want to be able to use 3 Infernal Machines at once, to ensure that I get one of each combination of bosses, but I'm not sure if I can have more than one key at a time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can get multiples of the same key before you craft the Infernal Machine.  Keys are stackable, though I'm not sure what the maximum stack size is.

Comment: at the minimum they stack to 100 like gems I believe.  The inferno machines are stackable too.

Answer (score -3):

You can only open one portal per game though, guess they didn't want you to be able to force all 3 types to open like with the sub-uber portals in D2.

Comment: This is completely wrong.  You can INDEED open all three portals in a single game.